# How can I compile Open CL on Mac OS X 10.6.3?

Tags: compiler-construction, macos, makefile, opencl

I was able to follow instructions and compiled CUDA 3.0  but cannot compile OpenCL that goes with it on Mac OS X 10.6.3?

Comment: Try asking on the nVidia CUDA forum at http://developer.nvidia.com

Answer (score 24):

I beleive nVidia under OpenCL suggests you just use the Apple drivers it provides by default. To compile an OpenCL program through gcc on OS X you simply use:

```
gcc -o foo foo.c -framework OpenCL
```

Comment: Sometimes you need to add the header files as well using `-I<ADDRESS_OF_CL_H>`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `clBuildProgram` in http://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-quick-reference-card.pdf. I believe the program must be compiled for each graphics card with you would like to target, much like each CPU architecture.